# viwUとかgUiwとかすることで単語の先頭へ移動したカーソルを直前の場所に戻したい

Tags: vim

ノーマルモードで<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>するとカーソル上の単語がアッパーケースになりますが、カーソルが単語の先頭へ移動してしまいます。
<kbd>C-o</kbd>で直前の位置へ戻ることを期待しましたが、まったく関係ないところへカーソルが飛んでしまいました。
どうすれば戻れるようになるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nnoremap v m`v
nnoremap g m`g
```

上記の設定をvimrcへ書きます。